# How to have activity in Android with a close button at the top corner?

Tags: android, android-activity

I would like to have an activity which would consist of a close button i.e 'x' at the right top corner closing the activity. Any examples on this will be very much helpful.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

make an `Activity` with Transparent theme in manifest like this:

```
<activity android:name=".MyDialogActivity" android:theme="@style/Theme.Transparent" />
```

and then define layout like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <RelativeLayout android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_margin="15dp" android:padding="2dp">
        <!-- Contents will go here..-->
    </RelativeLayout>
    <Button android:layout_alignParentRight="true" android:text="X"
        android:textColor="#FFF" android:background="@drawable/round_button_background"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:layout_margin="5dp" android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:layout_width="25dp" android:textSize="12sp" android:textStyle="bold"
        android:onClick="cancelActivity" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

and define a background for your close `Button` in drawable like this:

```
round_button_background.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:shape="oval">
    <solid android:color="#9F2200" />
    <stroke android:width="2dp" android:color="#FFF" />
</shape>
```

Comment: Thanks Adil how to make the activity center of the device vertical & horizontal....

Comment: when you will make `Activity` transparent and you will set `RelativeLayout` background to any of your desired color and you will see it is center of the screen

Comment: You should not use "sp" for dimensions like width and height. They are for Text only. Instead, use "dp".

Answer (score 2):

Use juzt have an x like image at the right top of corner. By pressing x image u can finish the activity.

XML:

```
        <ImageView
          android:id="@+id/close"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:align_parentRight="true"
          android:src="@drawable/closeimage"
          />
```

In Java Code:

```
       ImageView view=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.close);
       view.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
             Intent intent=new Intent(currentclass.this,statingclass.class);
              startActivity(intent);// here u can start another activity or just call finish method to close the activity.
              finish();

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

In your xml add one button view

syntax:

```
<Button android:id="+@id/close"
     android:text="close"
     android:layout_margin="5sp" 
     android:layout_height="25sp"
     android:layout_width="25sp" 
     android:onClick="closeActivity" />
```

and inside your activity or java class

syntax:

```
public void closeActivity(View v){

 Intent intent=new Intent(currentclass.this,statingclass.class);
 startActivity(intent);
 finish();
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe an "Up" button is what you really need instead of a close button. From the official Android documentation: "Your app should make it easy for users to find their way back to the app's main screen. One simple way to do this is to provide an Up button on the app bar for all activities except the main one. "

Details are described here: https://developer.android.com/training/appbar/up-action.html

Comment: The question is 5 years old. There was no Action Bar back then. Please focus your attention toward recent and unanswered questions. Thank you.

Comment: Why should I not give up-to-date answers to old questions that may be relevant now? At least I don't think this deserves a down-vote??

Comment: Up button is a standard nowadays. People who desire what was asked in the question wouldn't be satisfied with the Up button and would follow the accepted answer instead. This makes the answer immediately obsolete. This post could've been summarized into a comment instead.