# Close icon on the top left of a view

Tags: android, user-interface

This is a prototype UI maded by photoshop, you can see there is a `close` icon on the left top of the view.

[image]

I wonder if there is any control in android can implement this? If not, how to make it?

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8982678/how-to-have-activity-in-android-with-a-close-button-at-the-top-corner

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, You don't have. To get this kind of UI you just need to crop all the images separately and Use `Adapter` and inflate your custom layout.

In your case you need to create close icon image, put it in a ImageView and align it wherever you want.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will help you

```
<RelativeLayout
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_centerInParent="true"
     android:background="#00000000" >


<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_margin="20dp" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_margin="1dp"
        android:background="@drawable/show_alert_round"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

</RelativeLayout>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:background="@drawable/cross_button" />
```