# button on dialog that exceeds dialog border

Tags: android, button, dialog

Is there a way to draw a dialog with a button that looks like it exceeds the dialog's border. e.g. a Close button (X) that is half on the dialog and half way out of it. I have tried to keep an area on the dialog transparent to create the effect but the dialog still shows its border line. Is there a nice way to do it?

Thanks,
  Simon

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8982788/593709) is a method to do that

Comment: Can the same be done with a dialog rather than with activity?