# How to show Close[X] button at top corner of the popup window

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

[image]

I want to add a popup in my app like this in my UI, which will appear at the corener of the layout. Can any body help me how to doc close image like this.

I am taking frame layout in my code. Here is my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#FFFFFF" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    android:src="@drawable/closeImg" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="3dp"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_speciality_type"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Name: " />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="add:" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="phone :" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="3dp"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="abc abc abc" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="abc" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="230020202" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: you can create  a custom layoout for this and set a cross button on top right corner

Comment: That link may help:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/8982788/2949807
Please tell me if I mislead you

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because Its based on old sdk layouts .. in Android with New layout its very easy to manage layouts. Thanks.

Comment: So you are voting to close your own question only because it's old ? it can help people that are already with old app

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please check below code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="#FFFFFF" >



<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_margin="20dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="3dp"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_speciality_type"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Name: " />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="add:" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="phone :" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="3dp"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="abc abc abc" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="abc" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="230020202" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:src="@drawable/closeImg" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Thanks.

Comment: This is a proper solution

Answer (score 1):

:You can modify the layout xml code as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#FFFFFF" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    **android:layout_marginRight="-10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="-10dp"**
    android:src="@drawable/closeImg" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="3dp"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_speciality_type"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Name: " />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="add:" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="phone :" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="3dp"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="abc abc abc" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="abc" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="230020202" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

In facebook android sdk there is a WebDialog that does that, couple of months ago i used that as a reference to create one of my own.
Check out [Facebook-sdk-webdialog](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk/blob/master/facebook/src/com/facebook/widget/WebDialog.java) if you are interested.