# Custom dialog with Image outside boundaries of the view?

Tags: android

I'm trying to create a `Custom Dialog` like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9vLEs.jpg), I'm following this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20258730/custom-dialog-with-close-button/29026658#29026658) but changing the `layout_gravity` to this `android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|top"` and it puts on the center of the `Dialog` as I want, but the thing is that if I want to put the `ImageView` bigger it destroys the `xml`, also the `Dialog` itself it's too small because I only have a `TextView` and an `EditText` so what I'm doing wrong?

This is my xml.

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="15dp" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:background="#fff"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="10dp" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Choose the receiver"
                android:textColor="@color/blue"
                android:textSize="16dp" />

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                android:background="@drawable/edittext_style"
                android:hint="Username"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:textColorHint="@color/wallet_holo_blue_light" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </FrameLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|top"
        android:src="@drawable/icon_mail" />
</FrameLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

### OUTPUT

[image]

Also I've a `Drawable` to put it on the `Dialog` to create a border roundered with color and if I put it on `LinearLayout` it doesn't show up.

This is the rounded_border.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<item>
    <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
        <solid android:color="@color/white" />
        <corners android:radius="12dip" />
        <stroke
            android:width="1dip"
            android:color="@color/wallet_holo_blue_light" />
    </shape>
</item>
```

If I change the size of the `ImageView` happens this :

[image]

Comment: what do you mean by destroy? post an image.

Comment: @RahulTiwari Edited :D

Comment: **Read this** https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41563127/how-to-put-imageview-on-center-top-of-custom-dialog/56237742#56237742

Comment: @KeshavGera amazing!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="30dp">
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical">
                <View
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="0.5" />
                <View
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="0.5"
                    android:background="#fff" />
            </LinearLayout>
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="30dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:src="@drawable/icon_mail" />
        </RelativeLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:background="#fff"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="8dp">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Choose the receiver"
                android:textColor="@color/blue"
                android:textSize="16dp" />
            <EditText
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                android:background="@drawable/edittext_style"
                android:hint="Username"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:textColorHint="@color/wallet_holo_blue_light" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Just important that you keep `ImageView` width/height (30dp in the example) aligned with parent `RelativeLayout` height.

Comment: great... glad I could help you :)

Answer (score 0):

you need to put some padding in your root frame layout like this:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" 
android:padding = "40dp">
```

also put some negative margin for top in your image view

```
<ImageView
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|top"
        android:src="@drawable/icon_mail" 
        android:layout_marginTop="-20dp"/>
```

adjust the values as it suits.

additionally you are using one unnecessary `framelayout`, one immediately inside your root layout, you must be getting lint warning about it.

Comment: No difference... Also, what if I want to make this dialog like 250dp x 250xp ?

Comment: try using bigger values. for padding and margin.