# How to put imageview on center top of custom dialog?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-alertdialog

I am creating a custom dialog where I want to put `ImageView` on center top of dialog box how this can be done.

[image]

Comment: You can use FrameLayout for the same,
1.
make first element which is Orange Line box, give some margin from top.
2.Second create image view with center gravity ,second view of framelayout, which will show on top of your first layout .

Hope it will help .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put your `Views`, inside `LinearLayout` as per your idea.

Dialog method:

```
Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this);
    dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.mhp);
    dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
    dialog.show();
```

mhp.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@android:color/transparent" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="57dp"
    android:background="#f00"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
</LinearLayout>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Result(avoid BG)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
>




<LinearLayout
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="300dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="90dp"

     android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
   >
  </LinearLayout>

 <ImageView
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    />
</FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

[image]

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/_15dp"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:padding="@dimen/_10dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="110dp"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <View
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="0dp"
                        android:layout_weight=".47"
                        android:background="@drawable/white_transparent_k" />

                    <View
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="0dp"
                        android:layout_weight=".53"
                        android:background="@drawable/radius_top" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="110dp"
                    android:layout_height="110dp"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:layout_marginTop="-50dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/update_avilable" />
            </RelativeLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:background="@drawable/radius_bottom"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:paddingLeft="8dp"
                android:paddingRight="8dp"
                android:paddingBottom="8dp">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:padding="@dimen/_4dp"
                    android:text="@string/update_app_titile"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textColor="@color/black" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:padding="@dimen/_4dp"
                    android:text="@string/update_app_text"
                    android:textAlignment="center" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="@dimen/_10dp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:weightSum="2">
                    <!--#BDBDBD-->
                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/btn_cancel"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/_5dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/round_shape_fade_bg"
                        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/_5dp"
                        android:paddingLeft="30dp"
                        android:paddingRight="30dp"
                        android:paddingTop="@dimen/_5dp"
                        android:text="@string/update_cancel"
                        android:textColor="@color/white" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/btn_confirm"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/_10dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_5dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_10dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/round_shape_blue_bg"
                        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/_5dp"
                        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
                        android:paddingRight="20dp"
                        android:paddingTop="@dimen/_5dp"
                        android:text="@string/update_confirm"
                        android:textColor="@color/white" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>


            public void isAppUpdateAvailable() {
            LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity());
            View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.update_available_dialog, null);
            final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());

            builder.setView(view);

            final AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();
            alertDialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
            alertDialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));

            TextView btnConfirm,btn_cancel;
            btn_cancel=view.findViewById(R.id.btn_cancel);
            btnConfirm=view.findViewById(R.id.btn_confirm);

            btn_cancel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    alertDialog.dismiss();
                }
            });

            btnConfirm.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {              
                    alertDialog.dismiss();
                }
            });

            alertDialog.show();
        }


    **white_transparent_k.xml**

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <solid
            android:color="@android:color/transparent"/>
        <corners
            android:radius="15dp" />
        <padding
            android:left="10dp"
            android:top="10dp"
            android:right="10dp"
            android:bottom="10dp" />
    </shape>

    **radius_top.xml**

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <solid
            android:color="@color/white"/>
        <corners
            android:topLeftRadius="15dp"
            android:topRightRadius="15dp" />
        <padding
            android:left="10dp"
            android:top="10dp"
            android:right="10dp"
            android:bottom="10dp" />
    </shape>

    **radius_bottom.xml**

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <solid
            android:color="@color/white"/>
        <corners
            android:bottomLeftRadius="15dp"
            android:bottomRightRadius="15dp" />
        <padding
            android:left="10dp"
            android:right="10dp"
            />
    </shape>
```

Answer (score 0):

set this imageview in relative layout box and set these two property for imageview tag

```
 android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
   android:layout_marginTop="-50dp"
```

Comment: which properties?