# how to get cross button/image in custom dialog box border

Tags: android, popup, customdialog

I have used cutsom dialog box in my MainActivity for popup screen.I have added cross button to close 
 the popup screen. here in my code, that cross button is showing inside 
 the popup screen.
 Now what i want is it has to show at the border of the popup screen.
 please help me to get this..

Below is my code..any help would be appreciated...thanks in advance..

## Java File

HomePage.java

```
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Point;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Display;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment;

public class HomePage extends Activity {

final Context context = this;

Button b1;
Button b2;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home_page);

    b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button6);
    b2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button7);
    b2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent intent = new Intent(HomePage.this,RegisterPage.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }

    });

    b1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

      @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    @Override
      public void onClick(View arg0) {

        // custom dialog
    final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context);
    dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.activity_login_page);

        WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE); 
        Display display = wm.getDefaultDisplay(); // getting the screen size of device
        Point size = new Point();
        display.getSize(size);
        int width = size.x - 20;  // Set your heights
        int height = size.y - 80; // set your widths

        WindowManager.LayoutParams lp = new WindowManager.LayoutParams();
        lp.copyFrom(dialog.getWindow().getAttributes());

        lp.width = width;
        lp.height = height;

        dialog.getWindow().setAttributes(lp);
        dialog.show();


        ImageView image = (ImageView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.cancel_btn);
        image.setImageResource(R.drawable.cancel2);
        image.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                dialog.dismiss();
            }

        });
    Button dialogButton = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.button1);
    dialogButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
        //dialog.dismiss();
        Intent intent = new Intent(HomePage.this,CategoryPage.class);
        startActivity(intent);
            }
    });

        dialog.show();  
      }
    });

}
}
```

## XML File

activity_home_page.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#fff"

tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/header"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#fff"
        android:paddingLeft="0dp"
        android:paddingRight="0dp"
        android:paddingTop="5dip"
        android:paddingBottom="5dip">

 <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
    android:src="@drawable/miiskylogo" />

 </LinearLayout>

 <ScrollView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/header" >

  <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="163dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="0dp"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin" >


   <Button
            android:id="@+id/button6"
            android:layout_width="230dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:background="#00b0ff"
            android:layout_weight="0.1666"
            android:textSize="18dp"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:paddingLeft="3dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/lock"
            android:text="Login with SVAPP" />

   <Button
            android:id="@+id/button7"
            android:layout_width="230dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:background="#00b0ff"
            android:layout_weight="0.1666"
            android:textSize="18dp"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:paddingLeft="3dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/regis"
            android:text="Register with SVAPP" />
 </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

activity_login_page.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"

android:background="#fff"
tools:context="com.example.miiskyproject.Login" >

<ImageView
android:id="@+id/cancel_btn"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
android:src="@drawable/cancel2" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="130dp"
    android:layout_height="90dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="34dp"
    android:src="@drawable/miiskylogo" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="190dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/loginedit"
        android:ems="6"
        android:hint="User Name"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColorHint="#bdbdbd"
        android:textSize="13dp" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="190dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
        android:background="@drawable/loginedit"
        android:ems="6"
        android:hint="Password"
        android:inputType="textPassword" 
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColorHint="#bdbdbd"
        android:textSize="13dp" />



     <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
       android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="190dp"
        android:background="@drawable/loginbutton"
        android:ems="7"
        android:text="Login"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:textSize="12dp" />



</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/panelInsurance7"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    >
  <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="225dp"
        android:text="Forget Your Password?"

        android:textSize="13dp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

  </LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linear1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp">

  <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="280dp"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:text="Lorem Ipsum dolor sit amet,"
        android:background="@drawable/loginedit"
        android:textSize="18dp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

  </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

I want cross button something like the image below.
[Click Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bhdKR.jpg)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [custom dialog with close button](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20258730/custom-dialog-with-close-button)

Comment: You have not defined relative position of linearlayout below image view in  activity_login_page.xml

Comment: @camelcasecoder..even i am facing the same problem..dint got the solution yet..thats y posting here.

Comment: @Zero i dint get you.

Comment: It will be better if you post the exact image of what you desire.

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution:

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#fff"
        tools:context="com.example.miiskyproject.Login" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/cancel_layuot"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/cancel_btn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="130dp"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/cancel_layuot"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="34dp"
        android:src="@drawable/left_arrow" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/cancel_layuot" >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText1"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="190dp"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:ems="6"
            android:hint="User Name"
            android:padding="8dp"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:textColorHint="#bdbdbd"
            android:textSize="13dp"
            android:textStyle="bold" >

            <requestFocus />
        </EditText>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText2"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="190dp"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:ems="6"
            android:hint="Password"
            android:inputType="textPassword"
            android:padding="8dp"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:textColorHint="#bdbdbd"
            android:textSize="13dp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="70dp"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="190dp"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:ems="7"
            android:text="Login"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:textSize="12dp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/panelInsurance7"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="225dp"
            android:text="Forget Your Password?"
            android:textSize="13dp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linear1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/cancel_layuot"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="250dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="280dp"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:text="Lorem Ipsum dolor sit amet,"
            android:textSize="18dp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

You will see something like this:

[image]

Just replace image `ic_launcher` with the appropriated image.

Comment: in emulator even i am getting like that view..but when i run in my physical device it is showing inside only.whether i have to change something in  my HomePage.java ..?

Comment: make sure that you are not changing any view programatically.

Comment: I have edited the answer. Please try and replace your code with above code. This should work.

Comment: I have added cancel_btn in LinearLayout.

Comment: I have pasted ur code in my project.but same result..it is showing inside itself.have u checked in physical device..?