# How to make pop up ad windows when click a button?

Tags: java, android

1. i want to make an ad pop up when a "read more" button is clicked using android studio. the app is consist of an information like a list of article that should be click the read more if want to read full article
2. and then when the user click the button, the ad will appear, but the ad cannot be closed until the button of the ad is clicked

the uncloseable ad appearance is like this:

[image: the uncloseable ad appearance is like this]

3. finally when ad already clicked, the user will be redirected to play store or website, so the user can back again to the app and ad can be closed

the closeable ad appearance is like this:

[image: the closeable ad appearance is like this]

Comment: create a full screen dialog with transparent background

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make a simple android popup window?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38987442/how-to-make-a-simple-android-popup-window)

Comment: Well Please try this link > https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20258730/custom-dialog-with-close-button

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a PopupWindow. Read the docs here - https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupWindow.html

You can customize its appearance depending on your requirements.
Similar query has been already answered here-
[How to make a simple android popup window?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38987442/how-to-make-a-simple-android-popup-window)